# How to change format of geojson result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

If i do:

```
function app(e) {
    var $tar = e.target.getLatLngs();
    alert($tar);
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: app
    });
}
```

I get an alert with:

```
LatLng(19.08348, -155.54211),
LatLng(18.91619, -155.68817),
LatLng(19.05939, -155.93665),
LatLng(19.33888, -155.90806),
LatLng(19.70294, -156.07347),
LatLng(19.81422...
```

But i need to get the format like:

```
[19.08348, -155.54211],
[18.91619, -155.68817],
[19.05939, -155.93665],
[19.33888, -155.90806],
[19.70294, -156.07347],
[19.81422...
```

Comment: why i got a down vote i don't know...

Comment: we don't know what a LatLng is. Is it a subclass of Array? does it implement .x and .y? If the later, you can just map ```let arr = $tar.map(lngLat=>[lngLat.x, lngLat.y])```

Comment: @user753642 i am not sure to be honest, just learning leaflet. What I know is that i get that in an alert after a click, so I am only asking something like: ok i got this, how can this become that?

Comment: @user753642 It's a method of the Leaflet API. The OP has tagged it properly.

Comment: The `LatLng` object gives you the two properties you need. Look at the documentation (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlng). With that knowledge your question becomes *"How can I iterate an array and return a certain value for each item inside?"* and I'm pretty sure you will find a way to do this.

Comment: indeed, I missed it. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/LatLng.js) LatLng implements .lat and .lng, so it won't be this hard to replace x and y!

Comment: Not sure why the downvote; here's an upvote to balance things out.

Comment: @technophobia thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the array of elements and push them into a new array (with the desired format).  See **one** way of doing it below:

**UPDATED BASED ON CHAT**

```js
$(function() {
  // Assuming a whole bunch of latlngs  
  var target = [];  

  // these would come from your original e.target.getLatLngs();
  // I am just making some up for this demo
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var latlng = L.latLng(i, i);
    target.push(latlng);
  }

  alert(target);

  /* you only need the code from here on, right after your own alert(...) */
   
  // will hold the newly formatted values
  var newLatLng = []; 

  // convert to new format
  /** UPDATED Based on chat comments */
  $.each(target, function(index, value) {
    if( value.length ){
      $.each(value, function(ind, val) {
        var latLngArr = [val.lat, val.lng];
        newLatLng.push(latLngArr);
      });
    }else{
        var latLngArray = [value.lat, value.lng];
        newLatLng.push(latLngArray);
    }
  });

  console.log(newLatLng);
  alert(JSON.stringify(newLatLng));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i apply this i get `LatLng(0, 0),LatLng(1, 1),LatLng(2, 2),LatLng(3, 3),LatLng(4, 4),LatLng(5, 5),LatLng(6, 6),LatLng(7, 7),LatLng(8, 8),LatLng(9, 9)`

Comment: @rob.m on the initial alert, yes, on the output (to console) no - I'll also output to alert to illustrate

Comment: ok thanks, i can see them in the console, yet your code isn't getting the actual values (i know you made something up for the demo tho). But based on my question where i actually get the values, how would I implement it with yours?

Comment: @rob.m you only need to implement the second half - I'll add some comments

Comment: mm i did what you said but console says Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined(…)

Comment: @rob.m that's because your variable is not named `target` is named something else - `$tar` - replace `target` with `$tar` (or viceversa)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127132/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ochi).

Answer (score 3):

If it's just a formatting issue, then you can simply do this:

```
function app(e) {
   var $tar = e.target.getLatLngs();

   var formattedTar = $tar.map(function(obj) { // Loops through each Latlng object
       return [obj.lat, obj.lng]; // and returns an array instead
   });

   console.log(formattedTar);
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to print the array, try this instead:

```
   alert(JSON.stringify(formattedTar));
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn2Lgoxu/)

Comment: I would like to use this because is simpler than the other answer yet when i click i get in the alert `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to demonstrate printing the array of arrays.

Comment: i am getting null, null as values in the arrays

Comment: Are you getting `nulls` in the JSFiddle too?

Comment: I suggest you grab the code from the fiddle and make a runnable code snippet here at SO

Comment: Nope the JSFiddle is fine. The code I have doesn't do much more than what in my question, i mean the lat e lng i get them in the alert just as per the question. Therefore I am not sure what is causing the null, i see you have manually set the values yet i only get via `var $tar = e.target.getLatLngs();
    alert($tar);`

Comment: `getLatLngs()` returns an array of `Latlng` objects - that's what I was simulating in the JSFiddle.